# Jquery Accordion, keep open selected on Refresh / Page Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I try this code for my jquery Accordion

```
        (function(jQuery){
         jQuery.fn.extend({  
             accordion: function() {       
                return this.each(function() {

                    var $ul = $(this);

                    if($ul.data('accordiated'))
                        return false;

                    $.each($ul.find('ul, li>div'), function(){
                        $(this).data('accordiated', true);
                        $(this).hide();
                    });

                    $.each($ul.find('a'), function(){
                        $(this).click(function(e){
                            activate(this);
                            //alert(this);
                            return void(0);
                        });
                    });
                    var sPath = window.location.pathname;
                    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    var findvar=sPage;
                    var active = (findvar)?$(this).find('a[href='+ findvar + ']')[0]:'';

                    if(active){
                        activate(active, 'toggle');
                        $(active).parents().show();
                    }

                    function activate(el,effect){
                        $(el).parent('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').children('ul, div').slideUp('fast');
                        $(el).siblings('ul, div')[(effect || 'slideToggle')]((!effect)?'fast':null);
                    }

                });
            } 
        }); 
    })(jQuery);
```

But when i refresh page, all Accordion collapse.
But I want that when I refresh page. Keep selected Accordion open,  because my Accordion is Side navigation placed in Include (php). so one php file for all side Accordion navigation, So whenever I clicked on menu, page should be change and keep selected Accordion open.

Comment: you will have to set a cookie that records if the accordion is open or closed. then when the page loads, read the cookie and open/close the accordion accordingly. Take a look at the jquery.cookie plugin.

Comment: @MikeOram thank you Mike, can you provide link or source for it and how to set cookie. ? is JqueryUI is needed for it ?

Comment: Sure, you can download it from github, the readme on this page has all installation and usage instructions, its pretty simple:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @MikeOram Is there an y working example which use Jquery Cookie ?

Comment: I wrote this script the other day which does basically what you want I believe. It atleast shows how to use jquery.cookie
http://jsfiddle.net/pBN9x/

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't have to use a cookie, he could use web storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: How I Use it in My code? Sorry But I am new in Jquery. So if you could, than thanz

Comment: although web storage is faster and more secure than cookies it is not supported by <IE8 so depends on the support requirements.

Answer (score 0):

html is stateless, so you should persist your page or accordion state, if you post your page, keep your latest status in a hidden
On your server side read this status and send it back to your page
Now on your page load set your accordion status as it should be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the selected accordion data for that particular session then you can use any of the storage technique in the following order

> 1.Local storage of HTML 5
>
> 2.Cookie
>
> 3.Hidden Field
>
> //For keeping  the selected value for long time.
>
> 4.Database  (you can use ajax call to save the value in database)

then check if any saved value is there  in document ready and make that accordion open

```
$(document.ready(function(){
var selectedaccordianId = $("#hidSavedAccordinId").val();

 if($.trim(selectedaccordianId) != "")
{
 $("#" + selectedaccordianId).show(); 
}
}));
```